# Create Simple Data Class in Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning angular and trying to make a very easy hero list.

I have a list of hero in a json like this

```
    {
        "name" :"Bobby",
        "avatar" : "myHero1.jpg",
        "power" : "12",
        "description" : "the strongest"
    }
```

I load this json list in a component, where i want to display all of them in a table, and beeing able to click on them to see their stats in detail.

I want to cast that json in an simple typescript class/Object, so that I don't have to guess and hard coding `this.hero["stats"]` and just have `MyHeroClass.stats`.

My question is, in angular, where should i store this class, and how should I make it?

Does it have to be an exported component (with no html and css?) or can I make just a class somewhere and import it where i need it ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

Create a `hero.ts` file:

```
export class Hero {
  name: string;
  avatar: string;
  power: string;
  description: string;
}
```

then, in any where, you can just import that `hero.ts` file and use as a datatype like this:

```
import { Hero } from '@/hero';
...
hero: Hero = {
    "name" :"Bobby",
    "avatar" : "myHero1.jpg",
    "power" : "12",
    "description" : "the strongest"
};
```

voila! now you can leverage the intelligent code completion provided by the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class or an interface and define their properties

**Interface**

```
interface MyHero {
   name: string;
   avatar: string;
   power: number;
   description: string
}
```

**Class**

```
class MyHero {
   constructor(name: string, avatar: string, power: number, description: string) {  }
}
```

Comment: To match the input data, `power` should be a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a folder in your src folder adding all export ts file class in that folder

add a class file in naming user.data.ts

```
export class UserData {
name: string;
avatar:string;
power:string;
description:string;
}
```

import this class file in your service where you are calling your api's

```
import { UserData } from "../domain/user.data";
```

store your api data

```
getuserdata() {
        return this.httpc.get<UserData>(your_url + '/name/getusername');
    }
```

also in your component where you are using this you need to import

```
import { UserData } from "../domain/user.data";
```

and you can use this like

userdata : UserData = new UserData();

you can populate this userdata in function calling to service like

```
this.userdata = data.results;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a little more safety, you can try using [ts-data-class](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-data-class), which also provides a constructor, field validation and useful functionality like `copyWith` and `parse`.

Here's an example of how to use it from a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@vkbobyr/powerful-secure-typescript-data-classes-with-full-ide-support-and-minimal-boilerplate-85449396a562) on it:

```js
import {
  DTClass, DTParsers, Parsers,
} from 'ts-data-class';

class Cat extends DTClass<Cat> {
  breed!: string;
  name?: string;
  numLives!: number;

  protected get parsers(): DTParsers<Cat> {
    return {
      breed: (v) => (typeof v === "string" ? v : "stray"),
      name: (v) => (typeof v === "string" ? v : undefined),
      numLives: (v) => (typeof v === "number" ? v : 9),
    };
  }
}
```